# Access flashvar defined in HTML from child loaded swf? ANSWER PROVIDED BELOW

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs4, flash-cs3, flashvars

I have a flash var stored in my html file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var flashvars = {

        map:"mapGAcentury21.xml"

    };

    var params = {

        menu: "false",

        scale: "noScale",

        allowFullscreen: "true",

        allowScriptAccess: "always",

        bgcolor: "#FFFFFF"

    };

    var attributes = {

        id:"REMap"

    };

    swfobject.embedSWF("REMap.swf", "altContent", "840", "630", "9.0.0", "expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);

</script>
```

I have a flash application I developed in FlashDevelop. From within this Flash application I load a file called 728x90.swf.   I can freely edit my 728x90.fla file but I do not want to change my main flash application files.

How can I access the flashvars variable from within my 728x90.swf file?

EDIT:

```
The following codes traced "your variable is undefined" 
1. trace("your variable is " + stage.loaderInfo.parameters.flashvars); 
2. trace("your variable is " + loaderInfo.parameters.flashvars); 
3. trace("your variable is " + loaderInfo.parameters.flashvars.map);
4. trace("your variable is " + stage.loaderInfo.parameters.flashvars.map);
```

EDIT 2:
I pasted my entire javascript code into my original post. my flashvars are being passed into my main swf file called "REMap.swf" The REMap.swf

```
public var requestAd:URLRequest = new URLRequest("media/728x90.swf");
```

Then in a function the following code loads my 728x90.swf file

```
loaderAd.load(requestAd);
addChild(loaderAd);
loaderAd.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, promoLoaded);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the parameters of the parent swf by calling

```
parent.loaderInfo.parameters
```

Answer (score 0):

Your document object is a `MovieClip`. The flashvars associated with the MovieClip are stored in its `loaderInfo.parameters` property. Don't get the flashvars from `stage.loaderInfo.parameters` unless you want the flashvars associated with the original calling flash movie.

Edit to add:

Read about [how to pass flashvars to a flash video](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/164/tn_16417.html). I'm getting the feeling that you're trying to access a JavaScript object from flash. That can be done too, you'll just need to read up on [flash.external.ExternalInterface](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html)

Edit #2:

```
public var requestAd:URLRequest = new URLRequest("media/728x90.swf");
```

should probably be:

```
public var requestAd:URLRequest = new URLRequest("media/728x90.swf?map=mapGAcentury12.xml");
```

Check out what HTML is generated by the `swfobject.embedSWF` call. It might not be sending the flashvars correctly.

Comment: I'm not trying to change the flashvars, i just need to read it.

Comment: The following codes traced "your variable is undefined"
trace("your variable is " + stage.loaderInfo.parameters.flashvars);
trace("your variable is " + loaderInfo.parameters.flashvars);
trace("your variable is " + loaderInfo.parameters.flashvars.map);
trace("your variable is " + stage.loaderInfo.parameters.flashvars.map);

Comment: I've noticed that your "flashvars" are located in a javascript object. Flashvars are passed via the query-string of the url of the swf to be loaded. If you just want your script to access javascript, that's an entirely different question.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer:

Create a variable and name it whatever you want. I tried the following three:

```
var s1:String = stage.loaderInfo.parameters["map"];
var s2:String = this.root.loaderInfo.parameters["map"];
var s3:String = root.loaderInfo.parameters.map;

trace(s1 + " " + s2 + " " + s3);
```

The output: mapGAcentury21.xml null null

Answer:
In order to access flashvars of a parent swf from a child swf use the following code:

```
var s1:String = stage.loaderInfo.parameters["PLACE THE NAME OF YOUR FLASHVAR WITHIN QUOTATIONS"];
trace(s1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Phil is correct that:

```
var s1:String = stage.loaderInfo.parameters["map"];
```

will work, *but* it will **only** work if the child SWF has already been added to the stage. This happens one/some frame(s?) after loading is complete. 
You can listen the the event in the child like so:

```
public function instantiateChildClass(){
   trace(stage.loaderInfo.parameters["map"]); //throws error if this SWF has just been loaded into a parent SWF
   addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
}
private function init(e:Event):void{
   removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
   trace(stage.loaderInfo.parameters["map"]); //traces map param
}
```